# How to connect documentdb to a spark application in an emr instance

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I'm getting error while I'm trying to configure spark with mongodb in my EMR instance. Below is the command -

```
spark-shell --conf "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://admin123:Vibhuti21!@docdb-2021-09-18-15-29-54.cluster-c4paykiwnh4d.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false" "spark.mongodb.output.collection="ecommerceCluster" --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.3
```

I'm a beginner in Spark & AWS. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

DocumentDB requires a CA bundle to be installed on each node where your spark executors will launch. As such you firstly need to install the CA certs on each instance, AWS has a guide under the JAVA section for this in two bash scripts which makes things easier.[1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html#connect_programmatically-tls_enabled)

Once these certs are installed, your spark command needs to reference the truststores and its passwords using the configuration parameters you can pass to Spark. Here is an example that I ran and this worked fine.

```
spark-submit 
--packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.3  
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=  
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/tmp/certs/rds-truststore.jks  
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<yourpassword>"   pytest.py
```

you can provide those same configuration options in both spark-shell as well.

One thing i did find tricky, was that the mongo spark connector doesnt appear to know the ssl_ca_certs parameter in the connection string, so i removed this to avoid warnings from Spark as the Spark executors would reference the keystore in the configuration anyway.